# Node.js Express complex routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm new in Node.js and Express.

My question bind with routes in Express.js.

I need to match next url in my project: `example.com/?campaign=123&click=123`.

I've wrote next the next condition in the `app.get()` method:

`app.get('/?campaign=:id&click=:click', ...)` .

I've checked it in [express route tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) and all work fine, but not in my test server.

Please help me with my issue. Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you please share some code ?

Comment: require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const appPort = process.env.APP_PORT;

app.get('/campaign=:id&click=:click', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('campaign', req.params.id);
    res.coocke('click', req.params.click);
    res.redirect(301, '/');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));

Comment: please check answer

Comment: you need to use example.com?campaign=123&click=123 not example.com/?campaign=123&click=123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be passed any query params in route path, please check the documentation to [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

You just need to get the query params using `req.query`

Please use following code,

```
   // Requesting example.com?campaign=123&click=123
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    var campaign = req.query.campaign;
    var click = req.query.click;

    res.cookie('campaign', campaign);
    res.redirect(301, '/');

  });
```

Hopes this will help you!!

Comment: Maybe you right, but if I go to the url: example.com/?campaign=123&click=123 my handler won't work, because this url don't match my route "get('/', (req, res) ...)". I need something like this: app.get('/?campaign=:id&click=:click', ...) .

Comment: when you are hit url like http://localhost:3000/?campaign=123&click=123 which will map with route "get('/', (req, res) ...)".

Comment: You don't need to mention query params in route path

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, because my action don't save a cookies and don't do a redirect. It ignoring this action if I go through the next url: example.com/?campaign=123&click=123.  It just show me an index.html file witch I think pointed by default by the server. I'm sorry, what spend your time.